# Iterate over 2 lists in parallel in CLISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm newbie trying to iterate over 2 lists in parallel, like this:

```
(defun test-do* (l1 l2)
  (do* ((temp1 l1 (cdr l1))
        (var1 (car temp1) (car temp1))
        (temp2 l2 (cdr l2))
        (var2 (car temp2) (car temp2)))
       ((endp temp1) 'end-of-l1) ))
```

The problem is that I got an infinite loop in my code and I don't know why.
Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain exactly what you're trying to do, but this modification to your code fixes the infinite loop:

```
(defun test-do* (l1 l2)
  (do* ((temp1 l1 (cdr temp1))
        (var1 (car temp1) (car temp1))
        (temp2 l2 (cdr temp2))
        (var2 (car temp2) (car temp2)))
       ((endp temp1) 'end-of-l1) ))
```

Consider one of the statements in your `do*` loop:

```
(temp1 l1 (cdr l1))
```

Translated to english (in the context of a `do*` loop), this means: " This is not what you want, as the value of `l1` is never changing, and so `temp1` is assigned the same value on every iteration after the first. Consider this modification:

```
(temp1 l1 (cdr temp1))
```

This means: "On the first iteration, set `temp1` to the value of `l1`. On each subsequent iteration, set `temp1` to the value of `(cdr temp1)`." This way, the value of `temp1` on each iteration depends on the value of `temp1` on the previous iteration, and your loop steps through the list like you intended.

Comment: I did understand what you said, and I though I didn't know what do* does. It was just a small mistake(should be temp1 instead of l1), which caused my other big function never end.

Answer (score 3):

(loop for x in '(a b c d e)
      for y in '(1 2 3 4 5)
      collect (list x y) )

((A 1) (B 2) (C 3) (D 4) (E 5))